# Trying to deploy ASP.Net core website onto a debian server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, debian

I am trying to find a way to deploy a ASP.Net Core (version 6.0) Website onto a server provided by a domain provider.

The server is Debian and as far as I can understand I cant change things on the server except uploading the files required for the Website.

I have created a simple website in Visual Studio 2022, using MVC Framework. It has no database as it is not required.

So the issue is how would I go about deploying the website onto the server, I understand I have to change my files to be Debian compatible but also I read up on the documents from Microsoft, and they insist I need to install .Net onto the server. Which I cant seem to do.

I tried reading through other solutions but there doesn't seem to be any updated answers.

I am new to this so sorry if this has been asked before. but any help would be welcome.

Comment: Are you unable to do anything with the server? Can you send the .NET SDK compressed to the server and decompress it?

Comment: @Chen I have 2 new updates for this basically.
1-  Found the documents from Microsoft to turn your project to a self sustaining deployable package. In short i dont need to have .Net installed on the server.
2- I have been in talks with the host provider, and what i understand is that the server does have apache (which is something that can run the project files)

I just need to somehow run the .dll file of the project